# Is there an expression to describe a situation where someone could have helped you but they didn't?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, proverbs, proverb-requests

I would like to know if there is an expression that describes a situation where someone, perhaps your friend, was capable of helping you but they didn't or they chose not to?

Eg: He was was free. He could have come over and consoled me. But he __________________ [didn't help despite the fact that he could].

An expression or a proverb applicable in this situation will do.

Answer (score 2):

But he '**passed by on the other side**'.

This idiom refers to the parable of the Good Samaritan, where certain chose to leave the wounded victim lying on the road, passing by on the other side.

> To ignore or avoid someone who is in need of assistance. *We as a people cannot continue to pass by on the other side as thousands of our fellow citizens are left on the streets in poverty.*

[Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+by+on+the+other+side)

Answer (score 0):

"He could have come over and consoled me, but his behavior was **omissive**."

> - "characterized by omissions" -  [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/omissive)
> - "failing or neglecting to do" - [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omissive)

- Whenever there is a question about **omissive** or comissive behavior by an employee or an agency, an investigator's first move is to check the personnel files for ...

"He could have come over and consoled me, but he **turned a blind eye** to my problems."

> - "to ignore something and pretend you do not see it" - [**TFD**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+blind+eye)

"There’s so much suffering in the world, you can’t just turn a blind eye to it."

"She chose to turn a blind eye to what she suspected was going on."